# Group by, having in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

```
select df.id, count(distinct airports) as num
from df
group by df.id
having count(distinct airports) > 3
```

I'm trying to do the equivalent of the above in Python pandas. I've tried different combinations of `filter`, `nunique`, `agg`, and nothing is working. Any advice?

ex:
df

```
df   
id     airport
1      lax
1      ohare
2      phl
3      lax
2      mdw
2      lax
2      sfw
2      tpe
```

So I want the result to be:

```
id     num
2      5
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`SeriesGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
s = df.groupby('id')['airport'].nunique()
print (s)
id
1    2
2    5
3    1
Name: airport, dtype: int64

df1 = s[s > 3].reset_index()
print (df1)
   id  airport
0   2        5
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.groupby('id')['airport'].nunique().reset_index().query('airport > 3')
print (df1)
   id  airport
1   2        5
```

Answer (score 0):

use groupby and count:

```
df_new = df.groupby('id').count()
```

filter:

```
df_new = df_new[(df_new['airport'] > 3)]
```