# Using HAVING after a pandas group by

Tags: pandas

I was looking at the answers here: [Group by, having in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46387992/group-by-having-in-pandas)

The problem is, the second answer doesn't work if you do something like

```
homeruns = df(data['hr'].groupby([data['year'], data['team_id']]).mean())
```

because homeruns will be a series.

So what should the best workaround be for this situation?

Comment: I think the following might be of relevance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373660/converting-a-pandas-groupby-output-from-series-to-dataframe

Comment: Can you give `data.head()` to recreate what are you working on?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example